# Google Form won't scroll on my limited height, one page site on any iDevices

Tags: iphone, ipad, scroll, ipod-touch, google-forms

I'm working on a one page site that is width based and doesn't have a lot of height available for the form. I've tried scrolling="yes" but that didn't work. It is a long form, and I need to be able to scroll all the way down. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Google Sites or another host? If Google Sites - have you tried un-clicking "Automatically adjust site to mobile phones" on the Manage Site -> General page?  You would then have to adjust your site's layout to work for both desktop and mobile, but it might work.

Comment: No, I'm using another host. I embedded the form into it.

Comment: If you get it working, please vote up my answer too, I could really use the points ;) Thanks!

Comment: It did and I would, but I only have three reputation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things you can try depending on what you are doing and what your provider will allow. You will likely have to edit the HTML in order to do this but it won't be too much.

1) If you are using a hosting provider where you have access to the meta tags, try adding this to the top of the page:

> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height">
> ```

2) If you are using a hosting provider similar to Google Sites that gives you an option to "Automatically adjust site to mobile phones", try un-clicking it.

3) You can try placing it in an iframe if your provider allows iframes:

> ```
> <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width="500" height="180">
>
> YOUR FORM
>
> </iframe>
> ```

4) If you are using a hosting provider who allows JavaScript, you can try this solution:

> [Single Finger Scrolling Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921688/single-finger-scrolling-for-inner-contents-div-iframes-in-iphone-mobile-safari)

5) If you can change the css (either inline or with a separate css file) try setting this property:

> `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`

I hope one or more of these work for you, let me know if you need clarification or more help with any of them.